# Thread Interrupted sometimes works and sometimes not

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

Please help me with my problem. I have 2 JMenuItems, if I Click on Start it shall start and do stuff. If I click on Stop it shall stop :) 
After i clicked on Start, I click on Stop and sometimes it stops and sometimes not. But I want that it always stops.

What have I done wrong? :/

```
class DiashowListener implements ActionListener {
Thread td;
boolean ok = false;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Start")) { 

                td = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (bimg != null) {
                                while (!ok) {
                                    try {
                                        ...


                                     } catch (Exception e2) {
                                    }   
                                    frame.repaint();
                                }                       
                        } 
                    }
                });

                td.start();

            } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Stop")) {
                if (td != null){
                    ok = true;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

**EDIT:** ok I changed something, its working now, but: If I click on Stop it shall stop immediately.

Comment: Just a guess: try instantiating td somewhere outside of actionPerformed. The way it is now, there's a risk (maybe) that td references an entirely new thread. Edit: also in "Stop": td.interrupt(); and, moreover, see Dima's answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are interrupting the wrong thread (should be td). Second, the contents of the `try` clause that you omitted is actually important (some operations are uninterruptible). Finally, `Thread.isInterrupted` is likely not what you want to use, as the flag may get cleared by some unrelated code. Depending on what exactly you are interrupting, it may (or may not) be a good idea to just catch `InterruptedException`, and terminate in case it is thrown. A better approach is to add your own flag, that the thread will check instead of `isInterrupted`, and the event handler will set instead of (or in addition to) interrupting the worker thread.

Comment: Under a normal scenario where td was started (and only started once) Thread.currentThread() would return td, correct? Or only if td was actually running, not in a sleep or some kind of block?

Comment: No. `Thread.currentThread()` returns ... well, the current thread. One, that is calling `interrupt`.

Comment: @SergWoron Regarding your edit. Your setting/checking the `ok` flag needs to be synchronized or, better yet, use `AtomicBoolean`. If you want you thread to "stop immediately", you gotta be checking the flag more often (and again, the omitted contents of the `try` clause actually matters here). The way you have it now, the thread will stop as soon as the loop completes.

Comment: Added my own flag and check now more often :) Thanks